# Will my folder be included in my production build?

Tags: create-react-app, npm-scripts

I have the following folder structure:

```
my-app/
  my-folder
  README.md
  node_modules/
  package.json
  public/
    index.html
    favicon.ico
  src/
    App.css
    App.js
    App.test.js
    index.css
    index.js
    logo.svg
```

When I run npm run build from the my-app directory, will my-folder be included in the build? I have no references to the folder in my app.js nor index.html

Comment: It doesn't seem so based on the config of Create React App: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/folder-structure/ (However, if you import it from your `src` / entry files, it could be included)

Comment: no, you have configured your build script to include it